# The space of holomorphic sections are finite dimensional?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I start my question with a definition and some motivation.

Let $M$ be a symplectic manifold. A subbundle $P\subset TM^{\mathbf{C}}$ of the complexified tangent bundle is called a complex polarization if

1. $P$ is Lagrangian, i.e. Maximal isotroic, dim$P_m=n$, $\forall m\in M$, and $\omega(P,P)=0$
2. P involutive, i.e. if $X,Y\in P$ then $[X,Y]\in P$
3. dim$P\cap\bar P \cap TM$ is constant

Now, Introduce an hermitian form on $P$ defined by

$$b(X,Y)=i\omega(X,\bar Y).$$

Note that if $P$ is real, then $b$ is vanishes identically on $P$. Consequently, $b$ projects onto a non-degenerate form on the quotient  $P/{(P\cap \bar P)}$ and we denote it by $\bar b$. $P$ is said to be of type $(r,s)$ if and only if $\bar b$ has signature $(r,s)$ i.e. its matrix is $$diag(\underbrace{1,1...,1}_{r},\underbrace{-1,-1...,-1}_{s} )$$ for $0\le r+s=n-dim_{\mathbf C }P\cap \bar P$
. Then, $P$ is said to be positive if $s=0$. In the case if $r=s=0$ then $P$ is real

> Let $(M,\omega, J)$ be a compact Kahler manifold with positive-definite
>   polarization $P$, and $(L,\nabla)$ be prequantum data. Let
>   $$M_{quantum} = \left\{s\in \Gamma(L) \vert \nabla_Xs=0 , \forall 
>  X\in \bar P   \right\}$$ Then I can not see why $M_{quantum}$ is
>   fnite-dimensional?. I am looking for a referrence for finding a proof for this assertion "the space of square integrable holomorphic sections is closed."

Comment: Can you define precisely what you mean   by *Lagrangian* and  *involutive*?

Comment: Involutive, means, if $X,Y\in P$ then $[X,Y]\in P$. and Lagrangian means maximal isotropic

Comment: Maximal isotropic with respect to what bilinear form?

Comment: I am asking all these question because there is another   notion of polarization  used in a similar context. In that case  $P\cap \bar{P}=0$, by definition.

Comment: in the case $P\cap \bar{P}=0$ we say kahler polarization. and is special case of polarization

Comment: *Please* add all clarifications to the body of he question.

Comment: OK,  Mariano Suárez-Alvarez, for a long times we hadn't any new of you on my questions :) You see that I ask my questions with better motivation. :) . Happy new year

Comment: Maximal isotropic  with respect to **which bilinear form**?

Comment: Maximal isotropic with respect to symplectic form

Comment: What symplectic form do you use on the **complex** vector space $V^{\mathbb{C}}$? By definition, symplectic forms are **real** bilinear forms.

Comment: we assume $\forall m\in M$, dim$P_m=n$, which dim$M=2n$. and $\omega(P,P)=0$

Comment: I edited it again, it is ok now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bC}{\mathbb{C}}$ $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$ Suppose that $V$ is a finite dimensional real space equipped with an  almost complex structure $J$. Let $P\subset V^{\bC}=V\otimes_{\bR}\bC$ be a **complex** vector subpace.

Then $P^*=\Hom_{\bC}(P,\bC)$ is a quotient  of $V_{\bC}^*=\Hom_{\bC}(V^{\bC},\bC)=\Hom_{\bR}(V,\bC)$ . We  denote by $\Pi_P$ the projection  $V_{\bC}^*\to P^*$.  We define $\Pi_{\bar{P}}$ similarly. Now observe that $V^*_{\bR}=\Hom(V,\bR)$ is a  **real** subspace of $V_{\bC}^*$. For $\xi\in V^*_{\bR}$ we  set $\xi_{\bar{P}}:=\Pi_{\bar{P}}\xi.$

If the induced real linear map $\xi\mapsto \xi_{\bar{P}}$ is injective, then the answer to your question is positive.

To see this consider the differential operator  $\newcommand{\pap}{\partial_{\bar{P}}}$ $\pap^\nabla$ defined as the composition

$$ C^\infty(L)\stackrel{\nabla}{\to} C^\infty(T^*M\otimes_{\bR} L)\stackrel{\Pi_{\bar{P}}}{\to} C^\infty( \bar{P}^*\otimes L).  $$

Then

$$M_{quantum}=\ker \pap^\nabla=\ker (\pap^\nabla)^*\pap^\nabla. $$

If  the map $\xi\mapsto\xi_{\bar{P}}$ is injective, then the operator $(\pap^\nabla)^*\pap^\nabla$ is elliptic and it has finite dimensional kernel on the compact manifold $M$.

Comment: In your solution you have assumed $P\subset V^{\bC}=V\otimes_{\bR}\bC$ while we tae $P$ as subbundle of $TM\otimes \bC$

Comment: At every point $x$ in $M$ the fiber $P_x$ is a subspace of $V^{\mathbb{C}}$ where $V=T_xM$.

Comment: I am still waiting for second part of answer.

Comment: Once you have the corresponding ellipticity, the statement about the closedness is immediate: all holomorphic sections are smooth in particular square integrable. They form a finite dimensional subspace of a Hilbert space, hence it is a closed subspace. I reiterate my comment that your question needs to be more carefully formulated because the meaning of *isotropic* is trickier than you think.